# Spring Boot JPA PostgreSQL Web App - Internal Authentication Error

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to make a Web Application using Spring Boot which connects to a PostgreSQL db. When running the app in my IDE it seems to establish a successful connection with my db. However, whenever I attempt to login to the application it is unable to find information for the input user.

My code can be found below. It makes use of a User table and a Roles table in the DB and is joined using a user_roles joining table. The error message I receive can be found at the bottom.

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks!

**User Entity Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pxuser")

public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "tabid")
    private int tabid;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String username;

    @Column(name = "firstname")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastname")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String password;

    @Column(name = "active")
    private int active;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(name = "pxuser_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tabid"), inverseJoinColumns = 
    @JoinColumn(name = "auth_role_id"))
    private Set<Role> roles;

    public User() {

    }

    public User(User user) {
        this.tabid = user.getTabid();
        this.username = user.getUsername();
        this.firstName = user.getFirstName();
        this.lastName = user.getLastName();
        this.password = user.getPassword();
        this.active = user.getActive();
        this.roles = user.getRoles();
    }

    public int getTabid() {
        return tabid;
    }

    public void setTabid(int tabid) {
        this.tabid = tabid;
    }

    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public int getActive() {
        return active;
    }

    public void setActive(int active) {
        this.active = active;
    }

    public Set<Role> getRoles() {
        return roles;
    }

    public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
        this.roles = roles;
    }

    }
```

**Role Entity Class**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pxrole")
public class Role {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "auth_role_id")
    private int auth_role_id;

    @Column(name = "role_name")
    private String role_name;

    @Column(name = "role_desc")
    private String role_desc;

    public Role() {

    }

    public int getAuth_role_id() {
        return auth_role_id;
    }

    public void setAuth_role_id(int auth_role_id) {
        this.auth_role_id = auth_role_id;
    }

    public String getRole_name() {
        return role_name;
    }

    public void setRole_name(String role_name) {
        this.role_name = role_name;
    }

    public String getRole_desc() {
        return role_desc;
    }

    public void setRole_desc(String role_desc) {
        this.role_desc = role_desc;
    }
    }
```

**User Repository Class**

```
    public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer>{

    Optional<User> findByUsername(String username);

    }
```

**Security Config Class**

```
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = UserRepository.class)
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{

        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
//      .passwordEncoder(getPasswordEncoder());

    }

    @Override 
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http.csrf().disable();
        http.authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/").hasAnyRole("ADMIN", "USER")
        .antMatchers("**/admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
        .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/login")
        .permitAll();
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder() {
        return NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance();
    }


//  //Password Encoder Method
//  private PasswordEncoder getPasswordEncoder1() {
//      return new PasswordEncoder() {
//          @Override
//          public String encode(CharSequence charSequence) {
//              return charSequence.toString();
//          }
//          
//          @Override
//          public boolean matches(CharSequence charSequence, String s) {
//              return true;
//          }
//      };
//  }
}
```

**Custom User Details Service Class**

```
@Service
public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService{

    @Autowired
    UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException{

        Optional<User> optionalUsers = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

        optionalUsers.orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException("Not found: " + username));

        return optionalUsers.map(CustomUserDetails::new).get();
    }
}
```

**Custom User Details Class**

```
public class CustomUserDetails extends User implements UserDetails{

    public CustomUserDetails (final User user) {
        super(user);        

    }


    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {

        return getRoles().stream().map(role -> new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_" + role.getRole_name())).collect(Collectors.toList());

    }

    @Override
    public String getPassword() {

        return super.getPassword();
    }

    @Override
    public String getUsername() {

        return super.getUsername();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {

        return true;
    }

}
```

**Home Reource Class**

```
@Controller
public class HomeResource {

    @PreAuthorize("hasAnyRole('ADMIN', 'USER')")
    @GetMapping("/")
        public String index() {
            return ("<h1>Welcome</h1>");
        }

    @PreAuthorize("hasRole('ADMIN')")
    @GetMapping("/admin")
        public String admin() {
        return ("<h1>Welcome Admin</h1>");
    }

    @GetMapping("/login")
        public String login() {
        return "login";
    }

    @GetMapping("/logout")
    public String logout() {
    return "logout";
}

}
```

**application.properties**

```
spring.main.banner-mode=CONSOLE

# Database
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost/*DB NAME*
spring.datasource.password=*MY PASSWORD*
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.postgresql.Driver
spring.datasource.username=*MY USERNAME*

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=activity

spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true

#thymeleaf
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
spring.thymeleaf.check-template=true
spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=true
spring.thymeleaf.servlet.content-type=text/html
spring.thymeleaf.enabled=true
spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8
spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        user0_.tabid as tabid1_1_,
        user0_.active as active2_1_,
        user0_.firstname as firstnam3_1_,
        user0_.lastname as lastname4_1_,
        user0_.password as password5_1_,
        user0_.username as username6_1_ 
    from
        activity.pxuser user0_ 
    where
        user0_.username=?
2020-06-09 08:21:44.009  WARN 7792 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01
2020-06-09 08:21:44.009 ERROR 7792 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: relation "activity.pxuser" does not exist
  Position: 201
2020-06-09 08:21:44.017 ERROR 7792 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user.

org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:123) ~[spring-security-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:144) ~[spring-security-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:199) ~[spring-security-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:219) ~[spring-security-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:95) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:92) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:77) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:358) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:271) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119) [spring-web-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:373) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:868) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1590) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_251]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.35.jar:9.0.35]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [na:1.8.0_251]
Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:281) ~[spring-orm-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255) ~[spring-orm-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:528) ~[spring-orm-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:61) ~[spring-tx-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:242) ~[spring-tx-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:153) ~[spring-tx-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:149) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:95) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy85.findByUsername(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.synopsys.consultantdashboard.service.CustomUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(CustomUserDetailsService.java:25) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:108) ~[spring-security-core-5.3.2.RELEASE.jar:5.3.2.RELEASE]
    ... 51 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:103) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:42) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:99) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:2292) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2050) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.executeQueryStatement(Loader.java:2012) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:953) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:354) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2838) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2820) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2652) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2647) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:506) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:396) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1404) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.doList(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1565) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.list(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1533) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.AbstractProducedQuery.getSingleResult(AbstractProducedQuery.java:1581) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.criteria.internal.compile.CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.getSingleResult(CriteriaQueryTypeQueryAdapter.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_251]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$DeferredQueryInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:409) ~[spring-orm-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy98.getSingleResult(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution$SingleEntityExecution.doExecute(JpaQueryExecution.java:196) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.JpaQueryExecution.execute(JpaQueryExecution.java:88) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.doExecute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:154) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery.execute(AbstractJpaQuery.java:142) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor$QueryMethodInvoker.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:195) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:152) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:130) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:80) ~[spring-data-commons-2.3.0.RELEASE.jar:2.3.0.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:366) ~[spring-tx-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:118) ~[spring-tx-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-tx-5.2.6.RELEASE.jar:5.2.6.RELEASE]
    ... 60 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: relation "activity.pxuser" does not exist
  Position: 201
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2533) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2268) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:313) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.executeInternal(PgStatement.java:448) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgStatement.execute(PgStatement.java:369) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeWithFlags(PgPreparedStatement.java:159) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.executeQuery(PgPreparedStatement.java:109) ~[postgresql-42.2.12.jar:42.2.12]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(ProxyPreparedStatement.java:52) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.4.5.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.ResultSetReturnImpl.extract(ResultSetReturnImpl.java:57) ~[hibernate-core-5.4.15.Final.jar:5.4.15.Final]
    ... 97 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Remove  spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=activity  property and then try.

Comment: @karan007 Yes this worked! Such a simple fix when you know what you are looking for lol. Thank you so much!

Comment: Can you mark it as a correct solution, i am posting it, it will help others too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.default_schema=activity property

It will work..!!